# Vue Error: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "participants". Expected Object, got Array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm attempting to pass data from my Parent Component to my Child Component.

Parent Component:

```
export default {
  props: {
    bordered: true,
    striped: true,
    participants:
        {
        primaryAlias : '',
        primaryEmail : '',
        primaryAddress : '',
        primaryPhone: '',
      }
  },
```

Child Component:

```
    export default {
  props: {
    participants: [
        {
      type: Object,
      value: ''
    },
  ]
  },
```

However, I'm running into many prop errors. Currently I receive the error in my Child Component:

```
Vue Error: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "participants". Expected Object, got Array
```

However, when I attempt to rectify it like this:

```
export default {
  props: {
    participants: [
        {
      type: Object,
      value: ''
    },
  ]
  },
```

I receive the following error, again in child component.

```
Invalid prop type: "[object Object]" is not a constructor
```

I've tried rewriting many times, but nothing seems to work, happy to hear tips.

Answer (score 1):

update like below then hope solve the issue

when **participants** is object type:

```
    export default {
      props: {
        participants:
            {
          type: Object,
          default: {}
        },
      },
```

when **participants** is array type:

```
 export default {
      props: {
        participants:
            {
          type: Array,
          default: []
        },
      },
```

you can read more from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately while that did clear the Prop Type Error, my data is still not rendered.

Comment: i think you passed different type of data also. could you please prepare codepan

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and Object Should be Function as Default (ESLint Recommends):

```js
 export default {
      props: {
        participants:
            {
          type: Array,
          default: () => []
        },
      },
```

and

```js
 export default {
      props: {
        participants:
            {
          type: Object,
          default: () => {}
        },
      },
```